# What is @types/node package in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node v10 and I found that I have dependency issue when using a library.

In the `ldapjs` library, `lib\url.js` uses `const url = require('url')` and then `parsedURL = new url.URL(urlStr)` to parse the string to URL.

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): url.URL is not a constructor
```

with this line of code: `parsedURL = new url.URL(ldapurl)` in my React project.

However, under my environment, `'url'` actually refers to `node_modules\@types\node\url.d.ts` which doesn’t contain any `.URL(str)` method, thus the error.

What is `@types/node`? Is it related TypeScript? I don't use TypeScript in my project. Can I remove it?

If I run Node in the terminal, it works fine:

```
> const url = require('url')
undefined
> let purl = new url.URL("https://google.com")
undefined
> console.log(purl)
URL {
  href: 'https://google.com/',
  origin: 'https://google.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'google.com',
  hostname: 'google.com',
  port: '',
  pathname: '/',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '' }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: [`@types/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) is related to TS, yes. And it certainly does have a URL with a constructor that accepts a string, see [the source code](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/v10/url.d.ts#L70-L86). You're not using TS in the Node repl, so you're not going to get TS errors. Can you give a [mre] to illustrate what you're doing and what actually happens?

Comment: Those are typescript definitions. You can remove them, but vs-code relies on them for code-hinting. If **Automatic Type Acquisition** is enabled in vs-code, vs code might download type defs in the background.  If type definitions are outdated they can show existing properties as missing or the other way around. I think your best bet is to try to just update them. Maybe a `npm i -D @types/node@latest`. Or replace `latest` with whatever version you are using.

Comment: Also the file where you're saying that's a problem is JS, which doesn't use types anyway. This is currently an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731), it's unlikely finding out what `@types/node` is will actually solve your problem. What's the *actual error* that started you looking at this?

Comment: @jonsharpe But VS code can use typescript definitions with regular javascript. And you can reference type defs using jsdoc.

Comment: also a sidenote: If you remove the interfaces and delcarations you also losing intelliSense support that autocompletes your code

Comment: @ippi but that's used only for developer information, for autocomplete and the like. Presumably the OP went spelunking in `node_modules/` because of an actual issue, e.g. an error from that file, *at runtime*. And the types appear to be correct anyway, so it's not at all clear what the problem is.

Comment: Maybe he has turned off typescipt acquisition and just have old type defs. Automatic Type Acquisition is saved to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript (on windows). if you install typedefs with npm locally, vs-code will use those instead.  @jonrsharpe So how can you tell if the types on OP's computer are ok or not? (If he codes using the code hints, and the types doesn't match the library, there will be errors)

Comment: @ippi maybe they have, but again that **would not cause a runtime error**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have updated the question, I'm working on a React project, but I don't intent to use typescript. Why node looks for typescript types?

Comment: Node's core modules like `url` aren't available in the browser, so if that's a React app it won't work. It *doesn't* look for TypeScript types at runtime; what you've tried to import from `url` *simply isn't there*. `ldapjs` is presumably not designed for use in frontend code. You're seeing the type definitions only because that's what your *IDE* shows you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for your explanation. I think I need to move the authentication to backend then,

Comment: Yes; if you were trying to do it in the frontend you were likely exposing things that should be kept secret in the backend. Note that if you'd started with the actual error and context you'd likely got to this solution faster, I'd recommend reading that article on the XY problem and considering it next time you have a question to ask.

Answer (score 16):

As taken directly from [the @types/node npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node):

> This package contains type definitions for Node.js (http://nodejs.org/).

This package is used to load in all type definitions when using typescript in node. When you add other packages, you also have to add their typings if they do not include them by default.

As an example, imagine you want to use [`lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) in your typescript application, you will need to install the type definitions ([`@types/lodash`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash)) too.

You don't need to worry about all this when you are not using typescript.