# Is it required to install all @types/package when using Typescript in Node project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs

I am trying to enable TypeScript support using babel on my Node bakcend API project. But I am confused, why I need to install @types defination for all the packages, is it required for all the packages.

And what @type/node does?

Thank You, In advance.

I want to know, how to properly enable Typescript support on Node.js for API development.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103848/what-is-types-node-package-in-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Enabling TypeScript support on a Node.js backend API project involves configuring TypeScript to compile the TypeScript code into JavaScript, and using a tool like Babel to transpile the JavaScript code into a version that can run on Node.js.

Regarding your first question, installing the **@types** packages is only necessary for packages that do not come with their **own TypeScript definitions**. The **@types** packages provide type definitions for external modules that do not include them. So, if you are using an external package that has TypeScript definitions included, you do not need to install its corresponding **@types** package.

The **@types/node** package provides TypeScript definitions for the Node.js runtime and its modules. This package is **required for any Node.js project** that uses TypeScript, as it provides TypeScript with the necessary type information for the Node.js runtime and its modules.

I don't want to overcrowd this post with setup instructions, you can find various tutorials on your search engine how to set it up - here's one blog that looks reasonable for example - https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/node-starter-project/